# Setting background color on a WPF ContentView

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

It seems like setting the background color on a custom ContentControl has no effect. If I change the ContentControl to UserControl background color property works fine,

Is there a workaround to change the background of a content control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom controls the `Background` needs to [bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) in the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx), otherwise it is not used.