# Setting ContentControl's background color in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

For the life of me I cant seem to figure out this simple task of setting the ContentControl's background color:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Content03"
            Width="130"
            Height="130"
            Canvas.Top="50"
            Canvas.Left="400"
            Background="Yellow">
        <Ellipse Fill="YellowGreen" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        </Ellipse>
    </ContentControl>
```

Also tried doing this using styles but still doesnt work ;(

Comment: Use Template, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334187/setting-background-color-on-a-wpf-contentview

Answer (score 10):

A ContentControl has no visual prescence in itself, but is a container for a child control. Setting some properties on this control (like fontsize etc) is usually only a way of having those properties propagate down the visual tree, so they van be picked up by child controls (those that support it).

The best thing to do is this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Content03"
            Width="130"
            Height="130"
            Canvas.Top="50"
            Canvas.Left="400">
        <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <Ellipse Fill="YellowGreen" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to stick with ContentControl I suggest using Border instead.

When I've had the same problem, Border had the same Child property that I needed to only have one child and to easily switch it via code with a different object. Border uses Properties like Background correctly. Those Properties also work, if Child is null.

```
<Border x:Name      = "Content03"
        Width       = "130"
        Height      = "130"
        Canvas.Top  = "50"
        Canvas.Left = "400"
        Background  = "Yellow">

    <Ellipse 
        Fill             = "YellowGreen" 
        IsHitTestVisible = "True">
    </Ellipse>

</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but you could also change the template of the ContentControl in the style.  That can be overkill for some things, but in this case it's really just wrapping a ContentPresenter in a Border and some template binding:

```
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="StPortal">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This gives you the ability to set background, etc. properties that borders have, AND gives the ability to set things like font family and size that ContentControl has and Border doesn't...